# how to send html table from view to controller in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to send HTML table from view to controller.
i have table in view where i m displaying my data in grid now i have to send this grid data in HTML file to controller.i reach till here i created HTML file of my table and i have to send this file to controller.

```
<HTML>
<table>
<tr><TD> 12 <TD></tr>
</table>
</HTML>


var request = $.ajax({
                url: '..controllername/actionname?htmlTableValue'+htmlTableValue,//action method url which defined in controller
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult nameOfTheAction(string htmlTableValue)
        {
        }
```

reaching null values to controller
where it fails
to send data to controler

Comment: -1 for good question and good explanation and gave correct details :p , hey give me more details ya .It's not a quality question

Comment: man give answer i updatesd

Comment: What ? Sorry one more time tell me that ?

Comment: What have you tried to do?  If you show some code that you tried, but didn't work, people will be much more likely to help *fix* that code, than if you just say "I don't know what to do, please help."

Comment: please provide soln man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var htmlTableValue = "<HTML>
<table>
<tr><TD> 12 <TD></tr>
</table>
</HTML>";

var request = $.ajax({
                url: '',//action method url which defined in controller
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

Change you "data" section of ajax call as below

from   data: `JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue)`,

change to   data:  `JSON.stringify({ htmlTableValue: htmlTableValue })` ,

and then use the same controller function as it is. then check the result.

it worked for me, let me know for any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In View:-

```
var htmlTableValue = "<HTML>
<table>
<tr><TD> 12 <TD></tr>
</table>
</HTML>";

var request = $.ajax({
                url: '',//action method url which defined in controller
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
```

In Controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult nameOfTheAction(string htmlTableValue)
        {
        }
```

Comment: man it is passing parser error ,why? my html content is more than i mentioned above

Comment: please add with JSON.stringify()

Comment: var htmlTableValue = "<html>" + "<table><tr><td>12<td><tr><table>" + "</html>";
  
           var request = $.ajax({
               url: "../ts/Sport",//action method url which defined in controller
               type: 'POST',
               cache: false,
               data: JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue),
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
           });

Comment: html table value is null in controller